# How to push code from local git to github excluding media folder?

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

I am currently using local repo on windows to save my code. It basically keeps tracks of all the files and folder in the working directory. I now want to also push it to github every time I commit locally for backup purposes but exclude `public/images` folder since there is no need for images to be on github. I do `git commit -a -m "this locally commits all the files and folder including images"` for local repo so what can I do to push it to github but exclude a specific folder public/images.

The way I push to my github is

```
git remote add origin
git remote -v
git push origin master
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`push` and `pull` synchronize the commit histories of a repository and its remotes. There is no way to filter out certain files or directories (how should this deal with, for example, commits that affect files in ignored and non-ignored directories?).

If that is what you want, it sounds like `public/images` could be an entirely different repository. That could either be a git submodule (meaning the main repository would still keep track of commit IDs of the submodule in its history, but the submodule itself would not need to be published) or by initializing a new repo in `public/images` and adding it to `.gitignore` for the main repo as the other answers suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a file called `.gitignore` in your repo root directory and inside type the directories or files that you dont want to push.

eg)

```
#media
public/images
```

Comment: Just to clarify, wouldn't .gitignore also ignore the media folder while I am committing it locally?

Comment: yeah, it will ignore the files in your commits.

Comment: and one more thing, .gitignore exclude from commits only file that was created after been inserted on gitnore, to solve it you can use
    ```git update-index --skip-worktree filename```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use **.gitignore** file in your project folder. For your case you can use the following pattern:

```
*public/*
```

This will exclude all files in the folder "public".

Or to be more specific:

```
***/public/images*
```

This will exclude folder "images" in parent folder "public".

---

Please checkout documentation: [gitignore - Specifies intentionally untracked files to ignore](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)